# Bug with the vote limit notification

Tags: bug, voting, voting-limits

### **The bug here is the notification !**

I must confess.

I upvoted [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212198/rewarding-a-positive-user-experience) up when I reached my daily vote limit.

Before the crime :

> [image]

During the crime :

> [image]
>
> After the crime (refreshed):

[image]

You can go and see for yourself. It is still there.

Comment: That's nothing, I remember one day I casted over 200 votes... (hint: you get back the vote if the post is deleted)

Comment: Had a post you'd voted on possibly been deleted in the meantime?  Though I don't know why the notification would be displayed if this was the case

Comment: @Rory This is where the Bug tag comes into play.

Comment: Are you sure we didn't upvote at the same time. I can see my +1 there

Comment: @RichardTingle haha my vote is there. Anyways the problem is the Notification. Have I reached the limit or not.

Comment: @TimStone It is not my last vote. Since I earned the rep limit hat this morning. (few hours ago)

Comment: It's a blue informational message instead of a red "You did something you weren't allowed to do" message.

Comment: Err, but you said you reached your limit when you voted on that post?

Comment: Tim is right. The blue answers your question here. It's telling you that you just hit the vote limit. The fact that you have 41 votes for the day just means another post you'd voted on got deleted.

Comment: @TimStone Yeah it was reached a few hours ago I forgot about it. Then I tried voting and saw the blue box and said oh thats true but my vote was recorded. I think I might have a mix of both "issues". A post was deleted so I got to 39 without knowing, and then the last duplicate to which you are refering to happened. Let's close this one.

Comment: Not a bug, asking to change to something like "*you can* vote again in [abc]" will make sense though. :)